# Forcing use of attributes in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, attributes

Hi i want to forced to use this attributes in my XSD
now this attributes is optional

Attributes :

```
<xs:attribute name="namespace" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="uri" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="beforeMiddleware" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="afterMiddleware" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="accessLevel" type="xs:string"/>
```

And my XSD file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        version="1.0"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        targetNamespace="grif:route"
>

    <xs:element name="routes">
        <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="group" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                             <xs:element name="route" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                               <xs:complexType>
                                   <xs:complexContent>
                                       <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                           <xs:attribute name="action" type="xs:string"/>
                                           <xs:attribute name="uri" type="xs:string"/>
                                           <xs:attribute name="method" type="methodList" default="GET"/>
                                       </xs:restriction>
                                   </xs:complexContent>
                               </xs:complexType>
                           </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>

                        <xs:attribute name="namespace" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="uri" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="beforeMiddleware" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="afterMiddleware" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="accessLevel" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
           </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>


    <xs:simpleType name="methodList">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="GET" />
            <xs:enumeration value="POST" />
            <xs:enumeration value="PUT" />
            <xs:enumeration value="HEAD" />
            <xs:enumeration value="DELETE" />
            <xs:enumeration value="CONNECT" />
            <xs:enumeration value="OPTIONS" />
            <xs:enumeration value="TRACE" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

And my example XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<routes xmlns="grif:route">
    <group uri="/magazine" namespace="\Grif\Beans\BlogBeans" beforeMiddleware="LoginAuth">
        <route method="POST" action="NewsController@show" uri="/showNews" />
        <route method="GET" action="NewsController@archive" uri="/news" />
    </group>


    <group uri="/magazine/gallery" namespace="\Grif\Beans\MagazineBeans" accessLevel="ADMIN_ROLE">
        <route action="GalleryController@show" uri="/showGallery" />
    </group>
</routes>
```

How to change it to force use of attributes???
How to change it to force use of attributes???
How to change it to force use of attributes???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Attributes are optional by default. To specify that the attribute is
>   required, use the "use" attribute:
>
> ```
> <xs:attribute name="lang" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
> ```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_simple_attributes.asp